# access template of member function from other class

Tags: c++, class, templates, object

I am trying to change a private variable of a class inside an object, which is initialized inside that class. My intention can be drawn from the simple example below. the `Increment` called from obj should increase the `BaseClass::stuff`.

```
template <typename ObjectType>
class BaseClass{
 private:
  typedef int SampleType; // give custom name type
  int stuff = 0;
  ObjectType obj;

 public:
  int Increment(){
    return obj.Increment<SampleType>(stuff);
  }
};

class ObjectType{
  public:
   template <typename T>
   int Increment (T& stuff)
   {
      return stuff++;
   };
};

int main () {
  BaseClass<ObjectType> base;
  base.Increment(); // should increase stuff by 1;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to access `ObjectType::Increment` via `obj.Increment<int>(stuff);`, it gives me an error below:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
     return obj.Increment<SampleType>(stuff);
```

I am having a hard time seeing the cause of this problem.

Comment: It doesn't know that `Increment` is a template there. I don't remember the fix; maybe `return obj.template Increment<SampleType>(stuff)`?

Comment: @melpomene thanks the one you directed to solved the problem!